# How to get string converted to array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am kind of new to this, but this is giving me a headache.
Heres my code what i am trying to solve:

```
function parseComponents(data: any, excelAttributesArray: string[]) {
    let confs = "";
    let isValues = false;
    let listValues = "";

    if (!data) return confs;
    if (data["Part"]) {
        const part = data["Part"];
        excelAttributesArray.forEach((attribute) => {
            let attributeValue = part[attribute];
            if (attributeValue !== null) isValues = true;
            if (attributeValue !== null && attributeValue.Value) {
                attributeValue = attributeValue.Value;
            }
            listValues += attributeValue + ",";
        });

        const number = part["Number"];
        if (isValues) {
            confs += `${listValues}${number}`;
        }
    }
    if (data["Components"] && data["Components"].length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data["Components"].length; i++) {
            const tmp = parseComponents(
                data["Components"][i],
                excelAttributesArray
            );
            if (tmp && tmp.length > 0)
                confs += (confs.length > 0 ? "|" : "") + tmp;
        }
    }
    return confs;
}
```

The `confs` value is returned as a string. How do i get it return as array?

Comment: `let confs = []; confs.push(\`${listValues}${number}\`); `

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for me. It crashes in "unexpected token, in JSON position 4 error

Comment: There is no mentioning of JSON in your example whatsoever. You wanted an array, you got an array

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Look at the wrong error messages. 
Variable 'confs' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
Variable 'confs' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

These are the right errors.

Comment: I am not using typescript but if you change from string to array, you need to change the type too

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdoAQw) what you're looking for?  It's not really clear how you want the output array to be arranged; *maybe* each of those `confs += ` lines should be replaces with `confs.push()` but there's not enough information here to know.  Ideally you'd provide a [mre] including input/output requirements or at least an example.